# Javascript functions conversion to object notation passing variables

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, methods

I have a series of functions in javascript. Each function performs some action on a variable and then passes that variable onto the next function.

```
function first(){

    var variableOne = 1;

    second(variableOne);
}

function second(paramOne){

    var variableTwo = paramOne;

    third(variableTwo);
}


function third(paramTwo) {

    var variableThr = paramTwo;

    //etc
}
```

Each time the function returns the processed result, the varaiable is input as a parameter to the next function and continues as such.

I want to convert this style to OOP. However I am not exactly sure how to structure it and how to pass the variables to each method of the object in order properly. Here is what I have started, is this the best way to structure this object and methods?

```
var myObject() = function(){

    this.first() = function(){
    var variableOne = 1;
    //Proper way call the next method with the paramater as an input?
    myObject.second(variableOne);   
    }

    this.second() = function(paramOne){
    var variableTwo = paramOne;
    myObject.third(variableTwo);
    }

    this.third() = function(paramTwo){
    var variableThr = paramTwo;
    //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function definition seems not to be in correct format.Also it seems to be a constructor function. so have changed the function name myObject to MyObject(coding standard)

```
var MyObject = function(){
    this.first = function(){
    var variableOne = 1;
    //Proper way call the next method with the paramater as an input?
    this.second(variableOne);   
    }

    this.second = function(paramOne){
    var variableTwo = paramOne;
    this.third(variableTwo);
    }

    this.third = function(paramTwo){
    var variableThr = paramTwo;
    //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: How is this an off-topic question?

Comment: Please check the close reason. The question is, _"is this the best way to structure this object and methods?"_ which is opinion-based as everyone have their own favourite way of doing things.

Comment: What about if i said the most efficient way? Which is really what I was after.